# Does affect the NHibernate mapping inherited classes in C#?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two classes which have exactly the same code: one of them refresh constantly it data during a game and the other keep this data in the server for a new run of the game. I want to make an inheritance between these classes but i don't know if the NHibernate mapping overrides both of the classes losing the historical data.

Answer (score 1):

No, NHibernate supports several solid inheritance mapping strategies, and does not require you to inherit specifically from one of their classes.

Comment: Then you mean that i can make the inheritance and i don't lose the historical stored data?

Comment: That'll depend a bit on how you decide to map them, but generally yes. You shoudl be able to work it out w/o losing anything.